# Get smart phone/device location via API request

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, location

I'm looking for a service that will give me a phone or smart device's location via an API request over the web. Does something like this exist?

It would be nice if the service offered OAuth2 token security, but this is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) be what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think so, Google Maps Geolocation API takes geo coordinates (or and address) and returns addresses (or geo coordinates). I want to be able to request from a service on a user's behalf to get the user's current device's location.

Comment: So you want to be able to get location data of a phone, in general? If so, perhaps look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android).

Comment: Yes, physical location and smart device location.

Comment: I think the link provided in the comment above may help. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Ah, OK. This looks like it will work for devices on a mobile network. Anything for devices only on the internet?

Comment: Probably, but your location accuracy would go down (especially if they are on a mobile carrier instead of wifi). I know there are web API's that do this for HTML5.